# Are there any sets that are not complete metric spaces under all possible metrics?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

I don't have any particular set in mind but this seemed interesthing since completeness depends on the metric.

Comment: Do you really mean set here, or topological space? That is, do you want to consider *any* metric on a given set, or only those compatible with a given topology?

Comment: @AlexKruckman First one but I forgot about the discrete metric and Balloon's answer wrapped things up. Now, I think it would be better to talk of a norm, rather than a metric.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since every set can be given the discrete metric $d(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & \text{if $x\neq y$}\\0 &\text{if $x = y$}\end{array}\right.$, and that for this metric every Cauchy sequence is stationnary and so convergent, you can't find a such example.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the set of rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ in its usual topology is not a Baire space, so whatever compatible metric you put on it, it will be non-complete.

Comment: This depends on what the question is asking, precisely. If we view $\mathbb{Q}$ just as a **set** then obviously we *can* make it a complete metric space (and I think this is how the question leans, but I'm not certain).